Can I use the importmap-rails gem to replace yarn or can I use it with yarn?
I'm having trouble using importmap-rails to manage npm packages. I would ideally like it to function like yarn where it keeps track of versions, dependencies and downloads everything for you with a command like yarn install.
But it seems like importmap-rails is only set up to use a cdn when you pin something. Is this true? Or can it download packages and their dependencies with a command like yarn?
If it can't do that, can I use importmap-rails with yarn as my package manager? I tried this with underscore.js and ran into some issues.

Ran yarn add underscore, saw it was downloaded correctly and then added node_modules to the asset paths so that propshaft and importmap-rails would know to look there:

config/application.rb
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')

Then pinned the underscore folder:
# config/importmap.rb
pin_all_from 'node_modules/underscore', under: 'underscore'

Then imported the functionality I needed:
// from a custom js file
import debounce from 'underscore/modules/debounce';

Running ./bin/importmap json showed that the debounce.js file was found:
{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-bd82d6ab.js",
    "underscore/amd/_baseCreate": "/assets/underscore/amd/_baseCreate-7eccab16.js",
    "underscore/amd/_baseIteratee": "/assets/underscore/amd/_baseIteratee-5f781255.js",
    "underscore/amd/_cb": "/assets/underscore/amd/_cb-dd403ec6.js",
    "underscore/amd/_chainResult": "/assets/underscore/amd/_chainResult-4b98e265.js",
    "underscore/amd/_collectNonEnumProps": "/assets/underscore/amd/_collectNonEnumProps-ed4c206f.
...
    "underscore/modules/debounce": "/assets/underscore/modules/debounce-decaec4e.js",

And in the browser I didn't get any errors for debounce.js, it was fingerprinted and found, but inside of that file it was using relative paths to import other functions which caused 404 errors. Also there was a get request going to every single file in underscore, which is also not good.
15:41:34 web.1  | Completed 200 OK in 5482ms (Views: 2431.0ms | ActiveRecord: 557.1ms (24 queries, 6 cached) | GC: 368.1ms)
15:41:34 web.1  | 
15:41:34 web.1  | 
15:41:34 web.1  | Started GET "/assets/underscore/amd/_baseCreate-7eccab16.js" for ::1 at 2024-12-20 15:41:34 -0500
15:41:35 web.1  | Started GET "/assets/underscore/amd/_baseIteratee-5f781255.js" for ::1 at 2024-12-20 15:41:35 -0500
15:41:35 web.1  | Started GET "/assets/underscore/amd/_cb-dd403ec6.js" for ::1 at 2024-12-20 15:41:35 -0500
15:41:35 web.1  | Started GET "/assets/underscore/amd/_chainResult-4b98e265.js" for ::1 at 2024-12-20 15:41:35 -0500
15:41:35 web.1  | Started GET "/assets/underscore/amd/_collectNonEnumProps-ed4c206f.js" for ::1 at 2024-12-20 15:41:35 -0500
15:41:35 web.1  | Started GET "/assets/underscore/amd/_createAssigner-aa588b74.js" for ::1 at 2024-12-20 15:41:35 -0500
15:41:36 web.1  | Started GET "/assets/underscore/amd/_createEscaper-3ea6026c.js" for ::1 at 2024-12-20 15:41:36 -0500
15:41:36 web.1  | Started GET "/assets/underscore/amd/_createPredicateIndexFinder-f577fa32.js" for ::1 at 2024-12-20 15:41:36 -0500
...


debounce-decaec4e.js:1 
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/underscore/modules/restArguments.js 404 (Not Found)

debounce-decaec4e.js:2 
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/underscore/modules/now.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

debounce-decaec4e.js
import restArguments from './restArguments.js';
import now from './now.js';

So, can I use importmap-rails with yarn or instead of yarn for npm packages?
I've googled around and combed the documentation and there is only this brief description:
https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/blob/main/README.md#using-npm-packages-via-javascript-cdns
For extra context I just updated our rails 7 app to rails 8, so we just went from sprockets, yarn, webpacker to propshaft with importmap-rails. Happy to be without webpacker, but missing the yarn functionality.

You can use yarn to get the packages but you have to use ES module package:
pin "underscore", to: "underscore/underscore-esm.js"

import { debounce } from "underscore"


If you need just one function:
pin "/assets/underscore/modules/debounce.js", to: "underscore/modules/debounce.js"
# debounce dependencies
pin "/assets/underscore/modules/now.js", to: "underscore/modules/now.js"
pin "/assets/underscore/modules/restArguments.js", to: "underscore/modules/restArguments.js"

which  will allow for relative imports:
// app/javascript/application.js

// relative to the asset url
import debounce from "./underscore/modules/debounce.js"


To clarify the relative part, imports are relative to the url, and you can use ./ and ../ as needed to match the importmap, given you have the correct pin setup:
application                                          => import
application                                          => matches importmap
/assets/application-c10b436c.js                      => OK
        ⌄
      ./underscore/modules/debounce.js               => import
/assets/underscore/modules/debounce.js               => resolve relative url
/assets/underscore/modules/debounce.js               => matches importmap
/assets/underscore/modules/debounce-1fc53fe7.js      => OK
                           ⌄
                         ./restArguments.js          => import
/assets/underscore/modules/restArguments.js          => resolve relative url
/assets/underscore/modules/restArguments.js          => matches importmap
/assets/underscore/modules/restArguments-708796bd.js => OK


Alright, got it! Your first suggestion worked for me, adding some details below so I can use better formatting.

As said above, the first suggestion worked for me perfectly. Allows me to use yarn to manage dependencies and then I can link to them with importmap-rails.
Using the esm version was what was needed to fix the relative path issue that was generating 404 errors from within the underscore debounce.js file.
Kept the additional asset path in application.rb:
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')

Using the single pin to the esm js file instead of pin_all_from fixed the mountain of get requests to all of the various underscore files:
# config/importmap.rb
pin "underscore", to: "underscore/underscore-esm.js"

Then I could import just the one function I needed, and it correctly pulled in its dependencies:
// my-module.js:
import { debounce } from "underscore"

Here is my importmap from ./bin/importmap json:
{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-bd82d6ab.js",
    "underscore": "/assets/underscore/underscore-esm-91fff580.js",
    "src/image_modal_methods": "/assets/src/image_modal_methods-5c3fcc95.js",
    "src/search": "/assets/src/search-8b38146d.js",
    "src/sortable-table": "/assets/src/sortable-table-8ef04aa1.js"
  }
}

And just a little extra info for stuff I tried on the way. First I used the suggested route for a single function:
pin "/assets/underscore/modules/debounce.js", to: "underscore/modules/debounce.js"
# debounce dependencies
pin "/assets/underscore/modules/now.js", to: "underscore/modules/now.js"
pin "/assets/underscore/modules/restArguments.js", to: "underscore/modules/restArguments.js"

// app/javascript/application.js

// relative to the asset path
import debounce from "./underscore/modules/debounce.js"

This gave me a 404 for debounce.js:
http://localhost:3000/assets/src/underscore/modules/debounce.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I suspected this was because it wasn't looking in node_modules so I tried this:
# pin "underscore/modules/debounce"
# # debounce dependencies
# pin "underscore/modules/now"
# pin "underscore/modules/restArguments"

Which made sense to me because the name in the first argument to pin (as far as I understand) is the file name without the extension, with a path relative to either app/javascript or one of the other paths in Rails.application.config.assets.paths. And since I had added node_modules to the asset paths then underscore/modules/name made sense to me.
Then in my js file I imported my debounce function and its dependencies:
import restArguments from 'underscore/modules/restArguments'
import now from 'underscore/modules/now'
import debounce from "underscore/modules/debounce"

I didn't get any 404s from the imports, but I still got 404s from the relative imports within debounce.js - I assume this was because it was still the non-esm version.
debounce-decaec4e.js:1         
       GET http://localhost:3000/assets/underscore/modules/restArguments.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

debounce-decaec4e.js:2 
       GET http://localhost:3000/assets/underscore/modules/now.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

So - I'm not sure if there's a better way, but it seems to work nicely to do the following:

Manage dependencies with yarn
Add node_modules to asset paths
pin esm versions of dependencies
import functions needed


Edit: Following up post comments, I did get the second approach to work as well, though haven't confirmed in production. My issue was as Alex said that I was importing from within a module that was in a subdirectory rather than in application.js so I had to use ../ from that file.
In my importmap.rb file:
pin "/assets/underscore/modules/debounce.js", to: "underscore/modules/debounce.js"
# debounce dependencies
pin "/assets/underscore/modules/now.js", to: "underscore/modules/now.js"
pin "/assets/underscore/modules/restArguments.js", to: "underscore/modules/restArguments.js"


Then in application.js this works:
import debounce from "./underscore/modules/debounce.js"

And in my submodule, which is in app/javascript/src, this worked:
import debounce from "../underscore/modules/debounce.js"

All that said, the first approach seems cleanest to me since I'm still only importing the function I need so I think I'll go with that unless there's some reason not to. But I'm glad to see that both options work! And my other main problem was I was not using the esm version of underscore.
Thanks!

looks like you're importing from inside src/ directory, for relative import that means you need to move one directory up so that asset url matches the importmap: import debounce from "../underscore/modules/debounce.js"

Oh ok - yeah my js module with the import in it is in app/javascript/src. I'll give that a go for completeness. But I thought you weren't supposed to use relative imports because they could break in production?

pin "/assets/... makes relative imports work in production as well.

@Alex You were right, using /assets with ../ when I import from a subdirectory fixed my problem. Good to know there's another option! I updated my post above to include this option. Thanks again!
